# What can be the reasons why jquery cannot select element by id but can select element by attribut "id"

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, fullcalendar, laravel-blade

I am starting a project with full calendar (with Laravel backend). The agenda is well displayed and themed via jquery-ui theme.

When the user clicks on the agenda, the event is caught and a form made with blade is shown. All date inputs from the form can be retrieved and set with jquery. This is how I do it ([selection by id](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)) `$("#startDate").val(formattedStartDate)`.

For time inputs however this (`$("#startTime").val(formattedStartTime)`) does not work any longer and I have use the select via attribute method ([see JQuery own words](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) ) like this `$("input[id='startTime']").val(startTime);`

For information the input form is declared like this in the js file `{{ Form::time('startTime', null, [ 'id' => 'startTime', 'title' => 'Heure de début (obligatoire)']) }}`

and the blade macro that defines time input is declared like this in the view 
`{{ Form::macro('time', function() { return '<input type="time">'; }) }}`

I tried to change the id in blade but it did not change anything, and I also tried to use the input façade from Laravel Form:input('time', 'startTime, ...) without any changes.

My expertise in JQuery / Laravel / FullCalendar is very thin, and it looks very weird to me that these time inputs cannot be selected in the same way as the other inputs.

The generated HTML code is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
    <!--
    JQuery theme for the calendar
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">


    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   
    integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="   crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/lang/fr.js"></script>
    <!--
    To show the event description in a bubble
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/3.0.3/basic/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>


<style>
    /* ... */
</style>


</head>
<body>





    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <!-- Hidden div that serves as a placeholder for the jQuery dialog that shows event details
    -->
    <div id="eventContent" title="Éditer un RDV" style="display:none;">
        Début: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
        Fin: <span id="endTime"></span><br><br>
        <p id="eventInfo"></p>
        <p><strong><a id="eventLink" href="" target="_blank">Read More</a></strong></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Hidden div that serves as a placeholder for the jQuery dialog that creates new event
    -->
    <div id="newEventContent" title="Nouveau RDV" style="display:none;">
        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/23/agenda/storeRDV" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline" id="newEventForm"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="8MmMRBAt1ucjQfMk4Az0W5EBXMZRGlQrSVRmwoXF">

            <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <td>Titre*: </td>
                <td><input id="pTitle" title="Titre (obligatoire)" name="pTitle" type="text" value=""></td> 
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Début*: </td>
                <td><input id="startDate" title="Date de d&eacute;but (obligatoire)" name="startDate" type="date" value="2016-09-01"></td> 
                <td>à*: </td>
                <td><input id="startTime" title="Heure de d&eacute;but(obligatoire)" name="startTime" type="time"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>journée entière: </td>
                <td><input checked="checked" name="allDay" type="checkbox" value="false"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Fin*: </td>
                <td><input id="endDate" title="Date de fin (obligatoire)" name="endDate" type="date" value="2016-09-01"></td> 
                <td>à*: </td>
                <td><input id="endTime" title="Heure de fin (obligatoire)" name="endTime" type="time"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email: </td>
                <td><input id="pEmail" title="Email" name="pEmail" type="email" value=""></td> 
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Tél: </td>
                <td><input id="pTel" title="Num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone" name="pTel" type="number" value=""></td> 
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="saveRDVButton" type="button">Sauvegarder le RDV</button> 
        </form>

    </div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/js/scripts.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is the js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
                },
                theme: true,
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                lang: "fr",
                events: [
                {
                    title: "All Day Event",
                    start: "2016-08-01",
                    description: "Hello world!"
                }
                ],
    // Triggered when the user clicks on an event
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


                    // Clears the current selection
                   $(this).fullCalendar("unselect");

                }, // fin eventClick

                // Fired after a selection is made
                select: function(start, end, allDay) {


                    var startDate = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var startTime = moment(start).format("HH:mm");
                    var endDate = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var endTime = moment(end).format("HH:mm");



                    // Populate the dialog to show
                    $("#startDate").val(startDate);
                    // For the time fields why is it required to access via attribute to get the input time value ?
                    $("input[id='startTime']").val(startTime);
                    $("#endDate").val(endDate);
                    $("input[id='endTime']").val(endTime);

                    // Show the dialog
                    $("#newEventContent").dialog({ 
                        modal: true, 
                        width:500});

                    // New event is created
                    $("#saveRDVButton").on("click", function(e) {

                        e.preventDefault(); // We prevent the browser to submit the form (default action)
                        saveEvent();



                    });

                $(this).fullCalendar("unselect");
                } // fin select

            }); // fin full calendar init

    // Function saveEvent to be completed
 function saveEvent(){


                    // Let"s get the value from the form

                    var startDate = moment($("#startDate").val(), "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var startTime = moment($("input[id='startTime']").val(), "HH:mm").format("HH:mm");
                    var endDate = moment($("#endDate").val(), "YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var endTime = moment($("input[id='endTime']").val(), "HH:mm").format("HH:mm");

    // DO SOME TREATMENT (TBD)

} // end saveEvent

}); // fin document Ready
```

May somebody tell me if this is the expected behaviour that for time input one must select elements by attribute and the reason behind that ?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs with the same id?

Comment: @JasonP that makes sense... the select $("input[id='startTime']") is a bit more specific.

Comment: @JasonP this is the only input with that ID (I even tried to change the ID). Jeroen would you mind elaborating a little further ?

Comment: Can you include your html for the form?

Comment: @Culyx HTML and JavaScript added!

Comment: What does `console.log($("input[id='startTime']").length)` show you?

Comment: @Jason console.log($("input[id='startTime']").length) returns 1

Comment: I just tested this locally with both input types in chrome and it works fine, although I admittedly didn't use the fullcalender stuff. I'd guess that the full calender thing is what's messing it up for you? Have you tried using dev tools to see if fullcalender is doing something to your DOM?

Comment: As @JasonP mentioned. You have a **span** (in your eventContent div) AND later in the document in div newEventContent an **input** with id="startTime" - element ids should be unique. Right now $("#startTime") is probably hitting the span first, leading to your issue.

Comment: @smcd Ah, there it is.. Should have had him do `console.log($('[id="startTime"]').length)`.

Comment: @smcd You're completely right! I only focused on newEventContent div and forgot about the eventContent div. However I do remember having searched for other startTime instances in view with ctrl-f and changed this input ID with another ID without change.  I will test it as soon as I go back to this project, but now the mistake is quite obvious regarding the not unique ID. Thank you very much to all of you guys for showing me my mistake! I'll post back as soon as I've corrected the mistake so that your answer (or Jason's one) can be marked as the correct one.

Comment: OK so now I realized my mistake : instead of changing the ID while I was testing for conflicting IDs, I was changing the name in Blade template. That's why I saw it made no changes. Now I also realize that using IDs may not be the best solution in my case. Indeed because of their need for uniqueness, I'll have to choose IDs like startTimeEdit VS startTimeNew which does not fine me. Maybe that's the reason why Laravel Collective Form 5.2 does not generate ID by default. I've learned the hardway but I've learned a lot! Thanks again guys!

 @smcd how can I can mark your comment correct ?